# strengthening of Stein Factorization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth proper morphism of noetherian schemes. Consider the Stein factorization $X \xrightarrow{f'} X' \xrightarrow{g} Y$, where $f'$ has connected fibers and $g$ is a finite map. I have the following question

Question : Is it possible to claim something more about the properties of $f'$ and $g$. For example is it possible that either one or both of these maps are smooth/flat? How about in char 0?

My thoughts so far : If I want to prove that $g$ is etale then I must have $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ locally free. This statement will follow from Grauert's theorem once I could prove that number of connected components of fibers is constant. I am not sure how to proceed from here or even if this is a correct line of reasoning.

I would appreciate some counterexamples if nothing further could be said about the maps $f'$ and $g$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me assume characteristic 0 (I am a bit afraid of positive characteristic). Then indeed, $f'$ is smooth and $g$ is etale. Let us first show the second.

Since $g$ is finite, it is enough to check it is unramified. If $x'$ is a ramification point and $y = g(x')$, then $g^{-1}(y)$ is non-reduced at $x'$, hence ${f'}^{-1}(y)$ is also non-reduced, hence not smooth.

To show that $f'$ is smooth note that smoothness of a morphism is etale-local over the target, and $X'$ is etale-locally isomorphic to $Y$ by etaleness of $g$, so smoothness of $f'$ follows from that of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be a big help if you could the few details/references/hints to the following questions. 1. Why is $g$ flat? 2. I think it should be $f^{'-1}(x')$ is non-reduced, but I cannot figure out why is this true.

Comment: I am a bit skeptic about the flatness of $g$ since similar questions have been asked on overflow with inconclusive answers. Here are the links : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118329/stein-factorization-and-flatness/118341#118341 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65267/global-sections-of-flat-scheme-also-flat . Ofcourse my question has a stronger hypothesis and thus the result I am expecting might still be true.